# I want to Change the backgroud Colo of Specific Recycler VIew Item

Tags: android

I want to change the Background Color Green OF the Recycler View data Whose Status IS Ture and Set Backround Color RED whose status is False. [image]

The Round One Status is True and rest are False. 
So can any one tell me how i Differentiate ...

My Recycler View code Write Below.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DocRecycleAdoptor.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final EmpAttandance empAttandance = mDocs.get(position);

    holder.txtDocID.setText(empAttandance.getDOC_ID());
    holder.txtEmpID.setText(empAttandance.getEMP_ID());
    holder.dateTime.setText(empAttandance.getDATE()+" "+empAttandance.getTIME());
    holder.txtCoID.setText(empAttandance.getCO_ID());
    holder.txtStatus.setText(empAttandance.getSA());
    holder.empName.setText(empAttandance.getEmpName());

    if(empAttandance.getStatus() == "True"){
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    }else{
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

[image]

Now it Shows like This. 
But I want When Status is False Color Will Red. 
it didit hapen. 
top three Status are True And Other is false. 
Showing all in same color

Comment: in onbind check of list.getStatus == true ..change bgcolor.. else change bgcolor to white

Comment: you have given a background of white to your layout in your xml. if you remove it then it should work.

Comment: Post your item xml please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ANdroid == are Not working. so i use `empAttandance.getStatus().equal("True")` instead Of == and its working Fine.

Thanks to All of you Guys for helping me out. much appreciate.

```
if(empAttandance.getStatus().equal("True")){
//set your desired color on textview or a view for status true
}else{
//set your desired color on textview or a view for status false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your onBindViewHolder add below check

```
if(empAttandance.getStatus()){
//set your desired color on textview or a view for status true
}else{
//set your desired color on textview or a view for status false
}
```

Comment: what is the Proper Code for changing Background COlor of Specific view

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override public void onBindViewHolder(DocRecycleAdoptor.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
  final EmpAttandance empAttandance = mDocs.get(position); 
           holder.txtDocID.setText(empAttandance.getDOC_ID());
holder.txtEmpID.setText(empAttandance.getEMP_ID()); 
holder.dateTime.setText(empAttandance.getDATE()+" "+empAttandance.getTIME()); 
holder.txtCoID.setText(empAttandance.getCO_ID()); 
holder.txtStatus.setText(empAttandance.getSA()); 
holder.empName.setText(empAttandance.getEmpName());

   // this is it
 holder.rootLayout.setBackgroundColor(empAttandance.getStatus() ? GREEN : RED);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        inside your activity_docattd_list_items add linear layout.
        add inside linearlayout a drawable @drawarble/selector_gray_view.

        #selector_gray_view.xml
        <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient_gray_light"
                android:state_pressed="true"/>
            <item android:drawable="@color/clicked"
                android:state_focused="true"/>
        </selector>

        and after that add drawble @gradient_gray_light.

        #gradient_gray_light.xml
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="rectangle">    
            <gradient android:startColor="#30888888"
              android:endColor="#30888888"
              android:angle="90" />
        </shape>`enter code here`
        and after that add another drawable ,

        click inside your selector_gray_view.xml,
        @drawable/color. 

     and also intialize linearlayout in myviewholder.
     use it inside onbindviewholder like as: 
    holder.linearlayout.setonclicklistener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
 }
);
        happy coding.
```